# Home Security + Voice Communication Setup....How to do this?

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have several webcams and I have software that will provide a website I can visit and see all of the webcams.

I also want to add voice communication.  It can be one way; but I need to, from a remote location, be able to talk and have it come out of my speakers at home.

I don't know of any software that does this in any easy fashion.  Can someone recommend something for me?  I'm running Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have Skype and an account on the PC running the speakers at home. Have Skype on your end. Set Skype on HOME-PC to auto-answer, and every time you need to output your booming voice over to your HOME-PC, call your HOME-PC Skype account and speak.

Answer (score 0):

Give [eSpeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) it's a command line program, so it should be pretty easy to invoke via something like php, asp, or any server side langugage which can run command line.